# Concatenate values to get new column name and then use that column value for comparision

Tags: sql

Here is my SQL:
Table 1 questions:

| ID | question | option_1 | option_2 | option_3 | right_answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | what is your name | Raj | kiran | sandket | 1 |
| 2 | your pet name | bruno | Tommy | Undertaker | 2 |

Table 2 : member_answers

| id | q_id | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Raj |
| 2 | 2 | Tommy |

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as total_questions,count(ma.answers) submitted_answers,
    count(if(ma.answer = concat('option_',q.right_answer),1, NULL)) as correct_answers
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN member_answers ma 
   on q.ID = ma.q_id
WHERE AND  right_answer != 0;
```

Here `right_answer` holds an `int` value and the `answer` column holds text answer value.

Not able to configure out how to map concatenate two values and get third column value for comparison.

Here in if condition it is checking the answer value with the text 'option_1' if right_answer holds 1 as the correct answer. But i want to compare answer and option_1 column values. it is treating 'option_1' as text instead of column please someone help me.

Comment: You have not explained what you want to do.  What is your question?  Your query also refers to three tables but you have only shown examples from two of them.

Comment: Corrected the query.

Comment: `case right_answer when 1 then option_1 when 2 then option_2 when 3 then option_3 end`

Comment: If you would normalize your database design, you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing that I think you should consider is to normalize your tables and redesign it but however to answer your question, here is one way you can do it :

```
select
    count(*) as total_questions
    , count(ma.answers) submitted_answers
    , count(case right_answer when 
               1 then case when ma.answer = option_1 then 1 else null end 
               2 then case when ma.answer = option_2 then 1 else null end 
               3 then case when ma.answer = option_3 then 1 else null end 
            else null 
            end) correct_answers
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN member_answers ma 
   on q.ID = ma.q_id
...
```